# Code error creating Excel button in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, button

I am trying to add a button to an Excel worksheet in PowerShell as part of a bigger already coded and working script.

The button is not part of the Excel.Application COM object instead it is in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel namespace.

I've created the following code but it gives a TypeNot found error on the last line when run.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excel.visible = $True
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$Range1 = $worksheet.Range("A1", "A1")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel") 
$Btn = [Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel]::AddButton( $worksheet, $Range1, "Test")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dog

Comment: I Think that you need the `ControlExtensions` class from the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities` Assembly, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controlextensions.addbutton.aspx, it's the same namespace but not the same assembly

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look. Cheers